# How to get type of data reading from excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, file, types

I am trying to read data from an Excel file. Is there a way to check the type of data in each cell?

I have tried .GetType(); but the result is a very complicated class which didn't help.

here are parts of my code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

var a = range.Cells[1/*row*/, 1/*column*/] as Excel.Range;

var type = a.GetType();
```

**UPDATE:** For example, by runnig this line :

```
string MobileNumber = (string)(range.Cells[1, 7] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert type 'double' to 'string'

But this problem was solved with following code:

```
double tempValue = (range.Cells[1, 7] as Excel.Range).Value2;
string MobileNumber = tempValue.ToString();
```

Comment: what do you mean by type of Data ? you have a Range not a single cell. so it's type is `Excel.Range`. If you want to know what type of data a Cell contains then that's almost impossible to know. for example a `24`, is a valid integer as well as `string`,`decimal`,`double` and all numerical types.

Comment: if(type.toString().Equals("DateTime"))
{//it is date time}else if(type.toString().Equals("Double"))
{//it is double}

Comment: @Selman22 I don't think that it's true! see the update.

Comment: @Mary: What do you expect the value of .Value2 to be of an Excel Range? From MSDN: Returns or sets the cell value. Read/write. A range can be also 1 cell, then this makes sense. For multiple ones it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Charlie I get 'System.__ComObject' for all cells.

Comment: Can you afford to use Oledb?

Comment: You can read dataset .Datatypes are all same as excel